Child's teddies "being mean" after dark
Our child (7f) has got bruises on her upper biceps. We asked about it and she has been sucking and biting on her arms in bed. She says that she needs comfort because some of her soft toys are being mean, e.g. saying things like "I'm not listening to you".
We have talked about it and it seems related to some other children in class saying similar things. We are on school holidays at the moment (England), so there doesn't seem to be any school related fix here atm. The soft toys can be divided into kind and unkind, and the unkind half have been removed from her bed.
Is there anything else we should be doing? Is there anything deeper that we should be concerned about?

If taking away the unkind half of the toys helps, great! But it might be worth thinking ahead a bit to what you will do if you find that some of the kind toys have inexplicably turned mean. Since the "kind"/"unkind" distinction is in your child's mind, not in the toy, discarding toys is probably only a temporary solution -- it doesn't change the mind.

@user1751825 no answers in comments, please.

Other children in class saying similar things about their toys, or about people? if the latter, then including or excluding your child?

It's not uncommon for a child at that age to personify their plush toys, and to put their lived experiences into their play with the toys.
I would use this as an opportunity to role play with her how to handle meanness - it's what she's already doing, after all!  Take one of the 'mean' plush and help her talk to it in ways that are beneficial.  Also help her think about why the plush might say those things - it's possible this isn't "meanness" per se, but a normal part of the social dynamic.  If she can understand what the other person is feeling, she can better handle the interaction.

I like this. A variant would be one parent saying mean things as a mean plush and the other parent siding with the child and countering the mean things as a kind plush, ultimately defeating the mean plush.


Is there anything else we should be doing? Is there anything deeper that we should be concerned about?

Yes. Self-injury in children is something that needs to be taken seriously. Self-injury is not just cutting or burning oneself, although these are common means of self-injury in older kids. It is not necessarily associated with suicidal ideation (the common name for this is non-suicidal self injury (NSSI). Although self-injury in children your daughter's age is rising, not much is known about self-harm in children that young, as it more often presents in teens, but any self-injury is a sign of bigger stressors that need attention. It's an unhealthy coping mechanism to stress. In addition to parental support, the child coping with stress this way needs to learn better coping skills.
Several sources I scanned recommended talking about feelings with the child rather than talking about the behavior. This page from the UK gives details about self-injury and how you can help your child to learn healthier coping skills.
I'm not recommending having her see a therapist yet, but I very strongly recommend that you make an appointment with her primary care giver. As it's not a very uncommon condition, they should have some experience with it.
Kids and Self-Injury: What Parents Need to Know

Firstly I'd try to determine if she is in fact biting, or if she's just sucking on her arms. Sucking can cause superficial bruising quite easily, which isn't nescessarily painful at all, and may not be any cause for concern. The medical term is "mechanical purpura". People more often associate it with the common name "hicky". I remember doing this to myself as a child, at around that age, for no other reason than boredom, and being quite surprised that it actually left such a large obvious mark.
Biting is potentially more of a concern, as it's a deliberate action to hurt herself.
Regarding associating the behaviour with the way her classmates are treating her. This may be the reason, or it might be that you've asked her the question, and she's made up an answer. If she's otherwise not showing school related stress, I'd be inclined to just remain alert, but not alarmed. It really might be nothing of any significance.
Like I said though, first try to figure out if she really is trying to hurt herself. Those marks may potentially look a lot more serious than they are. Their skin is very soft at that age, and marks easily.

In addition to the good answers about the "mean toys" side, I would also recommend dealing with the root cause of the stress. Find out more about the school situation. Are these just a few incidents of meanness by classmates, or is she being systematically bullied and excluded?
If she is suffering from regular abuse then you should take it up with the school. They should have an anti-bullying policy; read it and ask them to implement it.

Could also mean that she is blaming the toys so she is not to blame and bear the "guilt" for giving her the "bruise/hicky". If this is accurate then maybe she has issues towards telling the truth or is in fear of being sanctioned? But it's hard to say by just imagining the situation. So, it's just a thought.

Take my words with a grain of salt; I'm in no way a prfessional.
Just what I see here, the biting seems to be an autistic tendency, and, I don't want to seem too panicky, but I feel like the soft toys being mean might be more than simply roleplaying, rather schizophrenia or something of the likes.
As for the biting, the reason I think this is because someone I know has a son that is diagnosed with autism. He used to put both hands completely in his mouth, soaking them in his own saliva, then take them out of his mouth and start rubbing them together. They also noticed teeth marks on his wrists, indicating that he would bite down slightly. Their solution to this was to replicate these sensory stimulations in more socially acceptable forms; hand lotion and a chewy necklace.
As for the schizophrenia, it just feels like a bit extreme to leave visible marks on oneself over something that isn't even real. Alas, this could be due to her age causing it to be more real to her, or potentially linked to the prior mention of autism. It just feels... off.
Anyhow, I would seek psychological assistance and maybe even evaluation if the psychiatrist deems it neccessary. This is obviously something that needs resolved, as she is leaving marks on herself over it.
Again, I am in no way a professional on this matter.
Note: when I say autistic, it's not neccesarily meant in an insulting or derogatory way (I, myself am autistic).
